# ArcMap ModelBuilder move file content

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

Is there a option / way in ModelBuilder to move the files I am processing in a Folder to a specific other folder (like the input folder - and done folder)?

I now Iterate files in a Folder, make a table of it,  and append to a geodatabase in a server.

So I don't need to move them everytime myself when it's all done.

Comment: Do you mean you want to set an output workspace?

Comment: just move the processed files. So yes, sounds like a output workspace

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script tool to insert into your model.

Here are the [instructions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/adding-a-script-tool.htm) for creating a script tool.

In the tool you will need 2 parameters:

- Source File - Direction is 'Input', Type is 'File'
- Output Folder - Direction is 'Input', Type is 'Folder'

Then save this code as a python file (.py):

```
import shutil

source = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

shutil.move(source, output)
```

You'll need to add this file as the source code for the script tool.

Then add this into your model.  You'll need to set the output of the 'Table to Table' tool (or whatever tool you are using to process the files) as a precondition for the 'Move Processed' script tool (In the image this is the dotted line going from test.dbf to Move Processed):

[image]

This will move each file to your 'processed' folder after it has run through your model.